# Who is depicted in Dragon Heist's cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, content-identification, art, waterdeep-dragon-heist

Who are the characters depicted in the cover of Dragon Heist?

[image]

I've just started DMing this, and I'm reading through the 1st chapter, but I don't recognize the characters here. The beholder in the background looks like Xanathar. None look like Volo or his missing cousin Floon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## These are the characters described in "Choose Your Villain(s)," in the introduction:

- The beholder looming behind is The Xanathar,
- the eyepatch- and large hat-wearing drow is Jarlaxle Baenre,
- the human couple are Victorio and Ammalia Cassalanter, and
- the hooded figure is one of Manshoon's clones.

And piled around them are pictured, of course, the eponymous Dragons.

Comment: That hooded figure is clearly Thanos, infinity gauntlet and everything.

Answer (score -2):

The dark elf with the eyepatch and the fancy hat is Jarlaxle, a character from the Drizzt series.

Comment: As has asked many times before, can you provide some backup for this answer?